How to mirror a MacBook Pro to two external monitors with different resolutions?
I recently switched from Windows to a MacBook Pro and encountered an issue with mirroring displays.
On Windows, I could mirror my screen to two external monitors while maintaining different resolutions for each monitor.
However, I haven’t been able to achieve the same on macOS.
Is there a built-in way to mirror to multiple monitors with different resolutions on macOS, or is there third-party software that can help with this?

Did you go into the display settings and choose which of the two scales is set to to govern the mirroring? Last I tried, you could choose the higher resolution or the lower  and pick whether the lower scaled up or the higher scaled down. What are your two displays set at when not mirrored?
